# htaccess: force download on parameter

Tags: .htaccess

My problem is that i want to force image files of every type and documents to automaticly download on click of the specific link.
You can use the attribute **download** but that does not work on every Browser so i need to send a different Request-Header.
**I can't just define a specific URL for that**, because that can change really quick and I'm using a CMS so the user likes to select manualy which files should be affected.

My solution was to add an Parameter like:

```
<a href="/some_folder_structure/some_image_here.jpg?download"
```

and check via htaccess if the Parameter *download* is there and redirect with forcing a download.

That's my Code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} download
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [T=application/octet-stream]
```

Can anybody of you see why it doesn't work?
Or should I try something else?